# How can I configure VS Code to run C# with Code Runner?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

My settings.json

```
"code-runner.ignoreSelection": true,    
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "javascript": "node",
    "php": "php",
    "python": "python -u",
    "powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
    "csharp": "scriptcs -script",
    "vbscript": "cscript //Nologo",
    "typescript": "ts-node",
    "coffeescript": "coffee",
    "pascal": "cd $dir && fpc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "scss": "scss --style expanded"
},
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
```

In Terminal:

PS C:\Users\avaa1\Desktop\Projeto\ConsoleProject> scriptcs -script "c:\Users\avaa1\Desktop\Projeto\ConsoleProject\Program.cs"
scriptcs : O termo 'scriptcs' não é reconhecido como nome de cmdlet, função, arquivo de script ou programa operável. Verifique a grafia do nome ou, se um
caminho tiver sido incluído, veja se o caminho está correto e tente novamente.
No linha:1 caractere:1

- scriptcs -script "c:\Users\avaa1\Desktop\Projeto\ConsoleProject\Progr ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (scriptcs:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: What is the program "scriptcs"?

Answer (score 3):

In VS Code Go to Settings, Search for " Code-runner:Executor Map "
There you find " Edit in settings.json "
open " settings.json "
inside JSON put the following Script:

```
 "code-runner.executorMap": {

    "javascript": "node",
    "php": "C:\\php\\php.exe",
    "python": "python",
    "perl": "perl",
    "ruby": "C:\\Ruby23-x64\\bin\\ruby.exe",
    "go": "go run",
    "html": "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\"",
    "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
    "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    
    "csharp": "cd $dir && dotnet run",
   
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure code runner to run with the command "dotnet run" like this:

```
"csharp": "dotnet run"
```

Also make sure that code runner is configured to run in the terminal.

```
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true
```

Answer (score -1):

you can run your code in terminal by using this command:

```
dotnet run
```

(make sure your terminal url must be in the project directory)